# Dynamically Moving multiple markers on google map without duplications

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, phonegap

I am working on a phonegap project with jquery mobile.I am new to the google map api.I am able to get array of markers from json and display it on map & I have used SetInterval function to get updated latitude and longitude from my database.
Problem is markers keep get overlap because of setInterval function.I found one solution from stackoverflow to remove duplicate marker but now I have two markers in my database but here its only showing one marker.I want to update these two markers without duplications.
My code till now(working only for one marker)

```js
 setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://dbmysite.net/getlatlongdriver.php",
                type: "post",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, status) {
                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            /* add a marker for each location in response data */
                            addMarker(item.latitude, item.longitude, item.username);
                            console.log(item.username, item.latitude, item.longitude);
                        });
                    });


                },
                error: function () {

                    $.mobile.loading('hide');
                    alert('unexpected error<br>try again later');

                }
            });
        }, 1000);

 function addMarker(lat, lng, username) {
            var labels = {
                text: username,
                color: 'black',
                fontSize: '40'
            };
            var icons = {
                url: "../www/img/marker.png", // url
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
            };

            var latlon = {
                lat: parseFloat(lat),
                lng: parseFloat(lng)
            }

            if (marker && marker.setMap) {
                // if the marker already exists, remove it from the map
                marker.setMap(null);
            }
            // create a new marker

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: {
                    lat: parseFloat(lat),
                    lng: parseFloat(lng)
                },
                label: labels,
                //                icon: icons,
                title: name
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (event) {
                map.panTo(this.getPosition());
                map.setZoom(16);

            }.bind(marker));
        }
```

Comment: `marker` can only store on marker. Try `var markers = [];` outside of `addMarker` and then use it to store your markers

(`markers.push(new google.maps.Marker...`)
If you keep getting the same set of markers from http://dbmysite.net/getlatlongdriver.php and only the location is changing, then have your `setInterval` function call a function that looks for the current marker in `markers`, creates the marker if it couldn't find the existing instance (using a version of `addMarker` that adds the marker to `markers`), and then updates the position of the marker it found/created.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Now I am able to update markers from database but problem is , markers are flickering on map.They should move on map according to new position any idea?? Below is my code..

Answer (score 0):

```js
            var map = null;
            var gmarkers = [];
            var intervalNumber = 0;

            setInterval(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://quickexample.com/FindMyRide/getlatlongdriver.php",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {

                        $.mobile.loading('hide');

                        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                                /* add a marker for each location in response data */
                                var lat = item.latitude;
                                var lng = item.longitude;
                                update_map(response, item.latitude, item.longitude);

                            });
                        });



                    },
                    error: function () {

                        $.mobile.loading('hide');
                        alert('unexpected error<br>try again later');

                    }
                });
            }, 3000);

            update_map = function (data, lat, lng) {

                var icon = {
                    url: "../www/img/marker.png", // url for custom marker
                    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
                    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
                };



                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                // delete all existing markers first
                for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);

                }
                gmarkers = [];
                // add new markers from the JSON data
                for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);
                    bounds.extend(latLng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: icon,
                    });
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        infoWindow.setContent(data.username + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                    (function (marker, data) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(data.username + "<br>" + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                    })(marker, data[i]);
                    gmarkers.push(marker);
                }
            };

            function initialize() {
                // initialize the map on page load.
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.1254, 72.9992),
                    zoom: 12,

                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                    mapOptions);
                // add the markers to the map if they have been loaded already.
                if (gmarkers.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
                        gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
                    }
                }
            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```